# Do ASP.NET Web Applications go "quiescent" after many hours of not being used?

Tags: asp.net, iis

We have a web application that is available 24/7, but since is a workday tool users tend to stop using it by the evening and don't come back in until around 6 or 7 am.  And very few users use it on weekends.

Some users who come in during off- or early-hours have noticed that the application isn't very responsive when they first start trying to use it.  One reports that on a few occasions it took between 3 and 5 signon attempts before they could actually sign in -- they'd get "An error has occurred loading your page".  Unfortunately we built this app without any logging function so we can get an idea of what is happening.

But, can anyone say anything about web apps going to sleep, so to speak, after several hours of non-use?  This application uses a Sql Server database located on a separate server, so it's also occurred to me that the difficulty could be caused by slowness of establishing contact with the Sql Server.

Comment: I don't think SQL ever sleeps, so I doubt the problem is there. Do you have a service layer? From what you're describing, it sounds like your website comes up ok, but maybe it's calling a webservice that lives elsewhere, and that service is the one having trouble waking up.

Comment: When the first request hits your app it can take a little longer, but this don't explain why there are 3 to 5 failed logins for the same user.

Comment: The failed logins are likely to be timeout errors.  Unfortunately, my suggestion to log errors was not implemented.  It's apparently only happening occasionally to first users in a day.

Comment: As an FYI: The reasoning behind this "feature" is to allow IIS to collect program memory that is not being used.  If no one loads a web page in 20 minutes (the default setting), it's assumed that web page is no longer being used, and the memory footprint of that program is taken out of RAM to free it up for other processes.  The next time any user loads the website, it will be slow while IIS reloads it into RAM.  And IIS isn't smart enough to know which parts to spin up first, so sometimes you get errors for the first few users while everything comes back online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design.  Some people use third party tools like Pingdom (https://www.pingdom.com/) to keep their websites alive.

Comment: OK, by design, but is this by design of IIS, ASP.NET, or Windows network?

Comment: IIS.  You can modify the timeout by modifying the advanced properties in your app pool.  There should be an "Idle Time-out (minutes)" setting.

Comment: Indeed. I initialy thought it was ASP.NET, but then I went on searching for that.I deleted my previous comment statig it was ASP.NET.

Comment: Yes, I found the Idle timeout setting.  It is set for 20 minutes.  I guess I can play with that and see what happens, or try pingdom.  Thanks for the information!